# How to access values of JSON object which is bound to State of component in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

I am getting JSON data from WebService and I am initializing it to the state. 
In UI, I want to directly bind a value to the textbox value field.

Here i was able to log the value of prod

[image: Value of prod]

But while binding the value to textbox I get error "Unable to get property of undefined or null reference":

[image]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as $ from "jquery";

interface IBudgetRequestReadOnly {
    data: [any];
}

export class BudgetRequestReadOnly extends React.Component<{ RequestNumber }, IBudgetRequestReadOnly> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [{}],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const RequestNumber = this.props.RequestNumber;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/GetRequestByRequestID",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { requestID: RequestNumber },
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg) {
                    this.setState({ data: msg });
                    console.log(this.state.data["product"].product);
                }
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (msg) {

            }
        });
    }

    public render() {

        return <div>
           <div className="col-sm-12 Card ">
            <div className="row">&nbsp;</div>
           
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <label>Product Need<sup>*</sup></label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                            value={this.state.data["product"]} disabled />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
        </div >;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include all code in the question in text format instead of linking to external images.

Comment: In your success callback you should log the result from the `setState` callback since `setState` is async.

Comment: To add to @Tholle's comment it would also help to see the rest of the component's code.

Comment: I have added my code,

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `this.state.data["product"].product` that is giving your error? You also initialize your `data` to an array with an empty object, put try to access it with `this.state.data["product"]` in the render method. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: this.state.data["product"].product is where i'm getting the error. While i'm doing this.state.date["product"] is showing [Object Object] in Textbox. But when i try to access the value inside it. Its throwing error.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the contents of `msg` when receiving it from your API? I could improve my answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your ajax request is asynchronous. Currently this is happening:

1. Your constructor is called.
2. render() is called
3. componentDidMount is called

The thing is that the `render` function you're trying to bind `this.state.data.product.product` but this doesn't exist (yet) on your first mount. Therefore trowing the error *Unable to get property of undefined or null reference* because `this.state.data.product` doesn't exist in `this.state.data`.

You could set a default value within your component state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: {
          product: {
            product: '',
          }
        },
    };
}
```

This will have `this.state.data.product.product` as an empty string by default, and upon obtaining your data from the API and updating the state, the actual `data.product.product` is set.

Now you can use `<input value={this.state.data.product.product} />` without getting an error.

Comment: Thanks for responding alserda but I was able to access this.state.data["product"] when product is just a key without any issue in the textbox value field. But when product is a object I am not able to access products children.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `msg` upon receiving the response from your API?

Comment: {
  "isNew": true,
  "productId": 2,
  "accountNumberId": 2,
  "units": 1,
  "unitCost": 1,
  "totalCost": 1.04,
  "category": "a",
  "dataSource": "a",
  "classExpense": "a",
  "initiative": "a",
  "currency": "a",
  "useFullLife": 12,
  "productSoftwareLicenseId": 319,
  "productSoftwareLicense": "a",
  "assetDescriptionId": 19,
  "comments": "a",
  "createdByName": "Teja Swaroop",
  "createdOn": "2018-07-13T11:50:00",
  "product": {
    "productId": 2,
    "product": "Upgrade",
    "isActive": true
  }
}

Comment: I've updated my answer, this should solve your problem.

Comment: Cant it be done without initializing the state with product object ? Can i know the reason. Doesn't the data hold all the values inside it without being defined ?

Comment: The data object _will_ contain all the values without them being defined, _after_ your API call is successful and you performed `this.setState`. But the `render` function is called __before__ the ajax-request is even sent out. And in the render function you're binding a property (data.product.product) when `data` _is_ defined but `data.product` is not. So the error thrown implies that it cannot bind `product`  (data.product.product) because the upper object (data.product) is not defined.  That's why you have to define it in the state if you're going to want to bind it.

Comment: But when i set textbox value={this.state.data.product} then it shows as [Object Object]. Even if im not defining data.product its showing that it is an object right.

Comment: Initially your textbox shows nothing because it’s undefined. After you receive data it will show [Object Object] because it is an object. Try and add a setTimeout on your http request and you’ll see, because you’re probably getting a response within a few ms now.